# constraint-layout in Android.Xamarin?

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, android-constraintlayout

Is there anyway to use constraint-layout (android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout) in Android.Xamarin (Native not Forms)? by using somehow jar files or something?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes , you can find it via Nuget here is the url, its for 1.0.0-alpha9

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout/

Comment: have you tried before or there any example for how using it

Comment: @MinaFawzy you just use it in xml layout like in native Android development. Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html